# Javascript working on second button click instead of first

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that I am trying to display and activate form information in on a button click. The table is set to "display: none" and the button is connected to the javascript. The javascript works but only after the button has been clicked a second time. I would like for it to work the first time it is clicked.

Button & Table HTML:

```
<button data-bind="click: addPatient" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Add Patient</button>
    <table id="newPatientForm">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:Patients">
            <tr>
                <td class="form-group"><input data-bind="value: FirstName, event: {change: flagPatientAsEdited}, hasfocus: true" /></td>
                <td class="form-group"><input data-bind="value: LastName" /></td>
                <td class="form-group"><button data-bind="click: $parent.removePatient">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the table CSS:

```
#newPatientForm {
    display: none;
}
```

This is the javascript that the button calls.

```
self.addPatient = function () {
        var divElement = document.getElementById('newPatientForm');
        var patient = new PatientViewModel({ SiteId: 0, FirstName: "", LastName: "", ObjectState: ObjectState.Added });
        if (divElement.style.display == 'none') {
            divElement.style.display = 'block';
            self.Patients.push(patient);
        }
        else {
            divElement.style.display = 'none';
            self.Patients.pop(patient);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Do this: `console.log(divElement.style.display)` and you will see why

Comment: @j08691 whoops. must have added that out of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the computed style when it is set in a stylesheet

```
function isHidden(elem) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
    return style.display === "none";
}
```

Change

```
if (divElement.style.display == 'none') {
```

to

```
if (isHidden(divElement)) {
```

which uses the above method.

It would probably bet better to just have a class that is hidden or not and toggle the class.

And finally, I do not think  `self.Patients.pop(patient);` is doing what you think it is doing. the `pop` method has no arguments. It does not find and remove elements.

Comment: I didn't add `pop` to remove elements from the array itself. I added that because each time I clicked the button to display the form, it was adding a form element for each click. So if I clicked the button to display the table/form 3 times, there were 3 forms displayed to add a patient in. I used the pop because that keeps it to only displaying 1 form no matter how many times it is clicked

Comment: Your suggestion for the isHidden change works! Thanks!